# Running dotnet on raspberry pi giving "No such file or directory" error

Tags: .net, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have been trying to install .net on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B and every time I try to run something like `dotnet --version` I get **No such file or directory**.

My Raspberry Pi is running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64.

I have tried installing the .net sdk using the following methods:

- [Install script/extracting binaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install)
- [This procedure meant for single-board computers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/iot/deployment)
- [Install with snap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap)
- [Default procedure for Debian systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-debian)

And for all this methods I always get the same **No such file or directory** error.

The main thing that has confused me is that, for all attempts, I have navigated to the installation folder for .net to confirm that the executable is there, and even try to run it from there doing `./dotnet` but the results are always the same.

For further debugging, I ran `file ./dotnet` and got this:

`./dotnet: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=b85d57f5844b53d635bf3215726b064df0da9283, not stripped`

I kept reading that the error could be that the installation was for 32-bit rather than 64, but the `file` command seems to show that it is compiled for ARM aarch64 which should be correct based on my understanding.

Any ideas? I would appreciate any input!

Comment: You seem to have installed it in your local path, but without the proper permissions, which will cause confusion. It's probably best to remove all traces of it and then follow only the description in your last link, that should work. It's even possible that for the latest version, the separate step to add the microsoft repository is no longer needed, but I can't verify this right now.

Comment: @PMF I think you were correct with your response, but I ended up installing Debian instead of Raspbian (not sure why there would be a difference) and it worked by following the Troubleshooting section under the last link on the description.